# Does $\sum \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2x}$ converges uniformly on $(0,\delta]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm already aware, by Parsevsal's theorem, that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2x}=\frac{\pi-x }{2}$$ 
is a pointwise convergence on $(0,\delta]$ for all $\delta\in(0,\pi)$. Now I'm wondering, is this convergence also uniform?

The first idea that popped into my mind was using [Dini's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem). However, since Dini's theorem requires all the functions to be defined on a compact set, it is not immediately available.

But is it possible to extend the definition of $\sin^2(nx)/n^2x$ to $x=0$ so as to make the redefined series fulfill all the conditions that Dini's theorem required? That's to say, can we define a series $\sum f_n(x)$ such that $f_n$ is defined on $[0,\delta]$ and that:
1). $f_n$ is continuous. 
2). $f_n(x)=\sin^2(nx)/n^2x$ except at $x=0$. 
3). $\sum_{1}^{\infty}f_n(0)=\pi/2$
4). $f_n\le f_{n+1}$ on $[0,\delta]$.

After doing some work I found that the answer is unfortunately no. Because by requiring (1) and (2), we must let $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, which contradicts (3).

So now I begin to doubt, is it the case that  the convergence just can't be uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\displaystyle R_n(x)=\sum_{k\geq n}\frac{\sin(kx))^2}{k^2x}$ for $x>0$. If your series is uniformly convergent on $I=]0,\delta]$ for some $\delta >0$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ and $x\in I$, we have $R_n(x)<\varepsilon$.

Now we have
$$R_n(x)\geq S_n(x)=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\sin(kx))^2}{k^2x}$$

Put $x=1/n$, it is in $I$ for $n$ large.We have
$$S_n(1/n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{(\sin(1+j/n))^2}{1+2 j/n+j^2/n^2}$$

Hence $S_n(1/n)$ is a Riemann-sum for $[0,1]$ and the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{(\sin(1+x))^2}{1+2x+x^2}$. So $\displaystyle S_n(1/n)\to \int_0^1f(t)dt=c>0$, and this contradict the uniform convergence of the series.

Comment: Another way to estimate your sum:
$$S_n(1/n) \ge \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\sin^2(1)}{k^2(1/n)}\ge n\cdot \frac{n\sin^2(1)}{4n^2} = \frac{\sin^2(1)}{4}.$$

Comment: @zhw Nice idea ! It simplify the proof of the lower bound, showing that Riemann sums is not necessary..

Comment: Bravo answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x$ small, the sum is close to $\pi / 2$ and yet as $x \to 0$, for fixed $n$ you have $\sin^2 (nx) / n^2 x \simeq (nx)^2/n^2x = x$. Thus as $x \to 0$ you need more and more terms in your series to get up to a particular fixed constant $c < \pi / 2$, so the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Ah sorry for the late feedback. Thank you for your answer. It was a pity for me that uniform convergence didn't hold because I would want it to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin^2x/x^2dx$. But I found an alternative and solved it at last. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the series converges uniformly on some $(0,\delta).$ Then by the standard result,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2x}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2x} = \sum_n 0 = 0.$$

But the series equals $(\pi-x)/2,$ which has limit $\pi/2$ as $x\to 0^+.$ That's a contradiction, proving that the original assumption is wrong.

Comment: Great! I didn't know how I could have missed this natural idea, perhaps because $0$ isn't in the convergence domain. But anyway, a result in Baby Rudin already proves this even if the limit point is not in the domain.