# Proving the uniform convergence for a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence which tend to $0$. I want to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx\left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}\right)^2$$
converges uniformly for all $x \ne 0$. I thought that using summation by parts could help here, but I'm not sure how to proceed any further. What do you suggest?

There's a similar question here, where $a_n$ is replaced by $1$. It's proven that in this case the series does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Also where did you see a proof of non-uniform convergence when $a_n = 1$?

Comment: Yep you are definitely correct. I need $a_n$ monotone also. Do you think that this result is wrong without that assumption? May we find a counterexample? I unmarked the accepted answer in case you can provide a better one. For the case $a_n=1$ here's the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546059/does-sum-frac-sin2nxn2x-converges-uniformly-on-0-delta.

Comment: @RRL : Well,  Dirichlet's test is in fact not relevant here, even when $(a_n)$ decreasing because the convergence of interest here is uniform convergence, not pointwise.

Comment: So you see it's still no use then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question comes from the following series inequality when $0 <x$,
$$ 0\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x \left( \dfrac{ \sin (nx)}{nx} \right)^2  \le 3$$
From that, you can bound your uniform converge by $2\sup_{k \ge n} |a_k|$

As this ineq is pretty loose, it's now up to your choice to decide what to do with it. Either you find the explicit formula for it, or either you can evaluate it as follows:
**Proof for the above ineq**

 If $x \ge 1$, the inequality is straight forward.

 Then for any $0<x<1$, we can find an positive integer $N_x \ge 2$, such that $$N_x\ge \dfrac{1}{x}  \ge N_x-1$$
By then, you'll observe that:
$$ \sum = \sum_{n=1}^{N_x} x \left( \dfrac{ \sin (nx)}{nx} \right)^2 +\sum_{n=N_x+1}^{\infty} x \left( \dfrac{ \sin (nx)}{nx} \right)^2  \le (N_x x ) + \dfrac{1}{x}\left( \sum_{n \ge N_x+1} \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \le \frac{N_x}{N_x-1} +N_x\dfrac{1}{N_x}\le 3$$
Done.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there an explicit formula for it? Maybe from fourier series?

Comment: Yeah, something related to complex log.

Comment: As pointed out by @RRL in the comments it turns out that this is not enaugh to prove uniform convergence, for we need a monotonic $a_n$. I dont want to accept this answer until I have a better understanding of this exercise. Hope you can help me again!

Comment: Well, this is enough, as I noted that you should bound your convergence by $\sup a_n$ ,not each $a_n$ alone. $$ \left\Vert  \sum_{k \ge n} a_k x \left( \dfrac{sin(nx)}{nx} \right)^2 \right\Vert \le \left(  \sup_{k \ge n} |a_k| \right) \sum_{k \ge n} |x|(\dfrac{sin(nx)}{nx})^2  \le 3\left(  \sup_{k \ge n} |a_k| \right)  $$

Comment: Ops you are right! Does it follows that the right hand side go to zero by $a_n \to 0$?

Comment: Surely, because $\lim a_n= 0$ iff $\limsup |a_n| =0$